# Reduce flutter apk size

Tags: flutter, dart

Can anyone tell me how do I reduce this apk size?
Some major contributors are classes.dex(3MB), Dart AOT symbols(6MB) and audience_network.dex(1MB).
The same applicative using native android can be built in just 4-5MB

Here are the results of --analyze-size.

C:\Users\arunc\AndroidStudioProjects\bonaza>flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64 --release --analyze-size
Running "flutter pub get" in miband5...                          1,807ms 
Building without sound null safety
For more information see [https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety\](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety%5C)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-5.0.1+1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionHandlerPlugin.java u
ses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     124.9s
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-release.apk (12.5MB).
▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
app-release.apk (total compressed)                                         13 MB
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

res/

```
drawable-anydpi-v21                                                     8 KB
interpolator                                                            1 KB
drawable-xxhdpi-v4                                                     56 KB
drawable-hdpi-v4                                                       33 KB
drawable                                                               21 KB
drawable-anydpi-v24                                                     2 KB
drawable-mdpi-v4                                                       24 KB
color-v23                                                               2 KB
drawable-xhdpi-v4                                                      40 KB
drawable-ldpi-v4                                                        6 KB
color                                                                   5 KB
mipmap-hdpi-v4                                                         19 KB
layout                                                                 28 KB
anim                                                                    8 KB
drawable-xxxhdpi-v4                                                    48 KB
mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4                                                      88 KB
mipmap-xhdpi-v4                                                        29 KB
mipmap-xxhdpi-v4                                                       55 KB
drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17                                              2 KB
mipmap-mdpi-v4                                                         10 KB
drawable-v21                                                            2 KB
drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17                                                1 KB
drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17                                               1 KB
layout-watch-v20                                                      1022 B
layout-v21                                                              2 KB
```

META-INF/

```
CERT.SF                                                                36 KB
kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module                                             1 KB
MANIFEST.MF                                                            32 KB
CERT.RSA                                                                1 KB
```

assets/

```
flutter_assets                                                         69 KB
audience_network.dex                                                    1 MB
```

kotlin/

```
kotlin.kotlin_builtins                                                  4 KB
reflect                                                                 2 KB
collections                                                             1 KB
```

AndroidManifest.xml                                                       6 KB

classes.dex                                                               3 MB

resources.arsc                                                          664 KB

lib/

```
arm64-v8a                                                               6 MB
Dart AOT symbols accounted decompressed size                            6 MB
  package:flutter                                                       3 MB
  dart:core                                                           405 KB
  dart:typed_data                                                     273 KB
  dart:io                                                             253 KB
  dart:ui                                                             215 KB
  dart:async                                                          173 KB
  dart:collection                                                     165 KB
  package:miband5                                                     152 KB
  package:parse_server_sdk                                            122 KB
  package:flutter_gen                                                 122 KB
  package:flutter_localizations                                       106 KB
  package:flutter_cache_manager                                       102 KB
  dart:convert                                                         83 KB
  package:sqflite_common                                               73 KB
  package:source_span                                                  63 KB
  package:win32                                                        53 KB
  package:intl                                                         50 KB
  dart:isolate                                                         39 KB
  package:vector_math                                                  34 KB
  package:google_mobile_ads                                            29 KB
```

▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒
A summary of your APK analysis can be found at: C:\Users\arunc.flutter-devtools\apk-code-size-analysis_09.json

Comment: It is normal for flutter apk to take 5-6MB more than a native app because it includes skia, flutter's rendering engine, as part of the apk.

Comment: check https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size and https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#how-big-is-the-flutter-engine - they say: *"In July 2019, we measured the download size of a minimal Flutter app (no Material Components, just a single Center widget, built with flutter build apk --split-per-abi), bundled and compressed as a release APK, to be approximately 4.3 MB for ARM, and 4.6 MB for ARM 64."*

Comment: run ``flutter clean`` before running ``flutter build`` command. Also, consider building ``app bundle`` instead of making raw ``apk``. More informaton @ https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android

Answer (score 4):

1. run `flutter clean`
2. run `flutter pub get`
3. run `flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi`

after running third commmand you'll get seprate apk's for android-arm , android-arm64 , android-x64 which reduces the apk's size.

Comment: I am already using that command. Please see in the question. flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm64 --release --analyze-size

Comment: yes i saw, but you haven't used --split-per-abi, use it and see if it works. if there is difference in size of apk, do let me know.

Answer (score -1):

for normal apk size build

```
flutter build apk
```

compressd build apk

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```